# Twitter OAuth API timeout (Nginx or Twitter ?)

Tags: node.js, oauth, twitter-oauth

I’m desperately looking for an answer to this question, is there a limit on the number of connections to a Twitter application?

My application makes several connections per minute, people connect to the application and sometimes the page does not load (it timeout I feel).

I use OAuth 1 for the app login, and then several workers turn around to analyze the user’s latest tweets and likes to generate an image. The generation is going well, but the login is blocked quite often, unable to connect to the site via the Twitter application.

I’m having a timeout with Nginx so I’m not sure where this is coming from.

> 2020/07/30 08:39:37 [error] 27739#27739: *751302 connect() failed
> (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client:
> 186.176.xxx.xxx, server: example.com, request: "HEAD /login HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://172.17.xxx.xxx:5000/login", host: "example.com",
> referrer: "https://example.com/login"

Or

> 2020/07/30 09:49:43 [alert] 27739#27739: *779078 could not allocate
> new session in SSL session shared cache "SSL" while SSL handshaking,
> client: 190.171.xxx.xxx, server: 0.0.0.0:443

When calling OAuth 1 (*from oauth NPM package : https://www.npmjs.com/package/oauth*), I didn’t get an error returned by Twitter, just a timeout after around 30 seconds.

Do you know if there is a limit on the number of Twitter app connections for users?

Answer (score 0):

The [Twitter API has rate limits per endpoints](https://developer.twitter.com/ja/docs/basics/rate-limits). If you hit the API too many times per time window (minutes, hours, days), the request will fail.